# How can I convert string to label in javafx?

Tags: java, string, javafx, label

In my project, a have a bunch of labels for some purpose. Since I am able to move them on stackpane using drag, I want to be able to save their new location in my app. So I was thinking about database, with columns for X and Y position, name of the label and its text.

However, since i want to use quite a lot of labels, I didn't want to code load of labels from database one by one, so I used this:

```
private void button_load(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
     String host = "jdbc:sqlite:C://app/app.sqlite";
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
         PreparedStatement pst = null;
         String SQL = "select * from labels";
         pst=con.prepareStatement(SQL);
         ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()){

         String name=rs.getString("Name");
         Double Y=rs.getDouble("Y");
         Double X=rs.getDouble("X");
         String Text=rs.getString("Text");

         name.setLayoutX(X);
         name.setLayoutX(Y);
         name.setText(Text);

        }}

         catch (SQLException ex)        
 {      Logger.getLogger(app.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}}
```

Obvious problem is, that I am not allowed to use content of the string ("name" in this case) for further use as label (`"string cannot be converted to label"`). I have been searching for some solution, but haven't found any.

So I would like to ask, is there a way, how to convert string to label or any other way that would help be in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are storing in the database? `text`, `x`, and `y` are pretty self-explanatory, but what is the "Name" column in the database table? Don't you just want to create a label from each row in the database (and presumably add it to your UI)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `Label` for each record and add it to your pane:

```
private Pane pane = ... // Or group or some other form of a container

private void button_load(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
         String host = "jdbc:sqlite:C://app/app.sqlite";
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
         PreparedStatement pst = null;
         String SQL = "select * from labels";
         pst=con.prepareStatement(SQL);
         ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()){
             Label label = new Label();

             String name=rs.getString("Name");
             Double Y=rs.getDouble("Y");
             Double X=rs.getDouble("X");
             String Text=rs.getString("Text");

             label.setLayoutX(X);
             label.setLayoutX(Y);
             label.setText(Text);
             label.setId(name);
             pane.getChildren().add(label);

        }
       } catch (SQLException ex){      
           Logger.getLogger(app.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
}
```

I am not sure what you store under name, my guess is that it could be the `id` of the node.